# Margins inside framelayout is not working in Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-2.2-froyo

i use framelayout and inside that i have 2 textview, if i use

```
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```

My layout is not showing proper in Android 2.2, while the same work fine in Android 4.0.

Here is the full code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text= "Testing String"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/LIGHTGRAY"

            android:layout_gravity="left|top"/>

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/ID_due_date"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
             android:text= "Testing String"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="left|center"/>
        </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In Android 2.2, it looks like this

[image]

In Android 4.0 ICS , it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in Android 2.2 (Froyo) and 2.3 (Gingerbread) where margins inside `FrameLayout` are not applied to childs without `layout_gravity` attribute set. You can see it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28057

The bug was fixed in Android 3.0 (Honeycomb).


Your issue is related with this bug. You have indeed a `layout_gravity` attribute set, so the margins are applied properly - views are offset by `10dp` from top and sides. Unfortunately `FrameLayout` doesn't know how to measure such childs so it's bounds are calculated without these margins - this is the reason why childs are cut at the bottom (`10dp`).
`FrameLayout` with height `match_parent` won't be affected with this issue, but in your case you have a `wrap_content` behavior set. (**Please notice** that even if you set the height to `fill_parent` it will still work as `wrap_content` because it's inside of `ScrollView`).

Please try to use paddings instead - in most cases (where background or clickable regions are not important) margins can be replaced by paddings.

Comment: Yes, padding works. but it wont cause me any problems right if i move to ICS, or other higher versions?

Comment: No, there will be no issues with paddings in this case. You can test it on ICS (or higher) if you want:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use padding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Testing String"
            android:textColor="@color/LIGHTGRAY"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ID_due_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Testing String"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```